# Start Play Store app in Android using navigation component

Tags: java, android, navigation, google-play

I have an Android application with a button to find other games on Play Store. This button should open the Google Play Store application. I have a working version which uses the `startActivity()` function and `Intent` flags, just as mentioned in [this official doc](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps?someapp")
                    .setPackage("com.android.vending");
this.startActivity(intent)
```

Is this possible to achieve using Navigation Components instead? I have tried implementing a [Navigation Deep Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link) and to set the equivalent of intent actions and data like so:

```
<activity
    android:id="@+id/playstore_activity">
    <deeplink
         app:uri="https://play.google.com/store/apps?someapp"
         app:action="android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW"
         app:targetPackage="com.android.vending"/>
</activity>
```

But I am getting an `ActivityNotFoundException: No activity found to handle Intent` error. What am I doing wrong? I am unable to find any further documentation of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end:

```
  <activity
      android:id="@+id/playstore"
      android:label="Travel to PlayStore"
      app:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
      app:data="@string/playstore_path"
      app:targetPackage="com.android.vending"
      />
```